# Unable to Integrating WSO2 Identity Server with Liferay for Authentication

Tags: liferay-6, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to work out Liferay Authentication using wso2 Identity Server,  I am using liferay 6.2 and Wso2 IS 5.0.0,  I am following above link https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Integrating+WSO2+Identity+Server+with+Liferay  Accordingly I have created portal-ext.properties file under liferay_home/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties. and added following properties in it:

auth.pipeline.pre=org.wso2.liferay.is.authenticator.WSO2ISAuthenticator
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false

but when I run liferay portal and try to log in I am getting     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.liferay.is.authenticator.WSO2ISAuthenticator  It should be in org.wso2.liferay.xacml.connector.jar but i am not getting this jar any where I tried to find out this class in other jars but unable to find it, I also tries to google it but no success,  Please help me out with this problem, Thanks

Comment: When we give a request to liferay does it redirect to WSO2 Identity server for login ? does WSOS2 Identity server create token and puts the token in Cookie and redirect it back to Liferay Home page ? What is the flow of login ? Sunil how did it work for you ?

Comment: Also the admin user of liferay i.e test@liferay.com changes to DOMAIN/test@liferay.com when i add a secoundry user store which is LDAP thus changing the username. but all these logins did not work and the login failed

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions in http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/10/integrating-wso2-identity-server-with.html. You can find the missing jars from https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/prabath/liferay.

Comment: http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html mentions so many jar files. axiom-1.2.9.wso2v1.jar
axis2-1.6.0.wso2v1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.0.wso2v1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.0.wso2v1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.0.wso2v1.jar
httpcore-4.1.0.alpha1-wso2v1.jar
neethi-2.0.4.wso2v1.jar
org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy-3.0.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.logging-3.0.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api-3.0.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.user.core-3.0.0.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.wso2v1.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.6.wso2v1.jar

Comment: Add org.wso2.securevault_1.0.0.wso2v2.jar and org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub_4.2.0.jar too.